# Can we connect to/from a Kafka compacted topic with the Flink kafka Upsert connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-table-api

This *feels* obvious, but I'm asking anyway since I can't find a clear confirmation in the documentation:

The semantics of the [Flink Table API upsert kafka connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/upsert-kafka.html) available in Flink 1.12 match pretty well the semantics of a Kafka compacted topics: interpreting the stream as a changelog and using `NULL` values as tombstone to mark deletions.

So my *assumption* is that it is ok to use it to consume from and produce to a compacted topic, and it's probably made precisely for that, although it should work fine as well with a non-compacted topic assuming its content is indeed a changelog. But I'm surprised not to find any reference to compacted topic in that part of the documentation.

Could somebody please confirm or infirm this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was made for use with compacted topics. According to [FLIP-149](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-149%3A+Introduce+the+upsert-kafka+Connector):

> Generally speaking, the underlying topic of the upsert-kafka source must be compacted. Besides, the underlying topic must have all the data with the same key in the same partition, otherwise, the result will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks. There were indeed more information in the FLIP, including the compacted topics and behavior of `UPDATE_BEFORE` events. All examples I see are only showing the sink side of the connector unfortunately, although the doc also describes the mechanism of the source to be what we expect, I think I get it now.

Comment: You can find an example using `kafka-upsert` as a source connector in [this repository](https://github.com/ververica/flink-sql-cookbook/blob/master/recipes/16/16_kafka_join.md).

Comment: Can you use regular kafka debezium avro format with compaction? Upsert Kafka doesn't seem to support debezium from what the docs say.

Comment: **Specifically as a source in my case.

Comment: @david-anderson The doc says: Generally speaking, the underlying topic of the upsert-kafka source `must` be compacted, but in my test, `non-compacted` also works fine for me, not sure I have missed something..